# kendo ui for angular AutoComplete wont open

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

iam trying to use the autocomplete component

data is loaded (i can see it on the HTML)

but when user types inside the textbox

nothing happens

any idea why ?

thank u

the HTML:

```
<kendo-autocomplete [data]="data"
                      [placeholder]="'e.g. Denmark'"
            class="countries" >
</kendo-autocomplete>
```

the TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-product-search-box',
    templateUrl: './product-search-box.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-search-box.component.css']
})
export class ProductSearchBoxComponent implements OnInit {

    public data: Array<string> = ["Albania", "Andorra", "Armenia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan"];

    constructor() {


    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

proof that data is loaded:
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console ? I tried your code and it seems to be working perfectly for me

Comment: no error at all

Comment: Hey I was wondering if you solved the problem ? If not could you email me your project at varunbabu008@gmail.com. I can have a look

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the `BrowserAnimationsModule` required for the popup animations:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platformbrowser/animations';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';

import 'hammerjs';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, HttpModule, 
DropDownsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Everything in the provided code seems fine otherwise. You should also check for console errors like already suggested.

Here is an working example:

[EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/HsUp2NhInFDwu5JzkBm6?p=preview)